# Wrap text around bottom left div?

Tags: html, css, bbcode

**I realise this question has been answered before. However, none of the solutions worked for me.** Or uh, I'm not doing them right, whichever.

Anyway. I need to wrap text in a container around a div in the bottom left corner. I can't margin-top/top the BL div since it doesn't wrap, and I can't absolute position it.

I need it to look like this:

```
------------------
|text text text t|
|ext text text te|
|xt text text tex|
|---|t text text |
|   |text text te|
-----------------
```

I'm coding this on a site that uses BBCode, so I'm a tad limited in what I can do HTML-wise, and I cannot use javascript/jquery.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7p2u1agc/), I've also attached the code below.

```css
.bg {
  width: 310px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  position: relative;
  font-family: tahoma, arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #772D99;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.desc {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px dotted #B07ACC;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pkmn {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px dotted #B07ACC;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="title">Title Here</div>
  <div class="desc">
    <div class="pkmn">
      <img src="https://pfq-static.com/img/pkmn/q/4/r/8.png/t=1482399842" />
    </div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `float: left;position: relative;` to your element and add a spacer element like seen in the code below.

```css
.bg {
  width: 310px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  position: relative;
  font-family: tahoma, arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #772D99;
}
.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
.desc {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 165px;
  border: 1px dotted #B07ACC;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pkmn {
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px dotted #B07ACC;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="title">Title Here</div>
  <div class="desc">
    <!-- I used CSS, but inline will serve well here -->
    <div style="float: left; width: 0px; height: 120px"></div>
    <div style="float: left; clear: left">
      <img src="https://pfq-static.com/img/pkmn/q/4/r/8.png/t=1482399842" class="pkmn"/>
    </div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It took a bit of adjusting to get all the positionings right, but this pretty much worked. Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height` to take required height of content and remove `padding-top` to stay content in div and add `display:inline-block` to take required height of div.

If i something missed in css or html so take a look in fiddle code

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9mrq82u/)**

Udate css part

```
.desc {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 115px;
  /* height: 70px; */
  border: 1px dotted #B07ACC;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  padding: 3px;
  /* padding-top: 70px; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Update HTML part

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="title">Title Here</div>
  <div class="desc">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    <div class="pkmn">
      <img src="https://pfq-static.com/img/pkmn/q/4/r/8.png/t=1482399842" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 310px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  position: relative;
  font-family: tahoma, arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #772D99;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.desc {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 115px;
  /* height: 70px; */
  border: 1px dotted #B07ACC;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  padding: 3px;
  /* padding-top: 70px; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pkmn {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px dotted #B07ACC;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #FCF2FF;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="title">Title Here</div>
  <div class="desc">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    <div class="pkmn">
      <img src="https://pfq-static.com/img/pkmn/q/4/r/8.png/t=1482399842" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does not look like the mockup in the question where you can see two lines of text.